# As a tourist in Doha, what are the rules on drinking alcohol in hotels?

Tags: regulations, hotels, alcohol, qatar, doha

The [Wikivoyage page for Doha](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Doha#Buy) has this to say on buying alcohol there:

> You can buy pretty much anything you want in Doha, apart from pork products and alcohol (except with a licence or in the major hotels)

That certainly gives you the idea, but is a bit light on the details of what is and isn't allowed if you are staying at or visiting a higher end hotel.

I'm currently staying in a hotel in Doha which does serve alcohol, but I don't want to get either myself or any staff of the hotel into any trouble. Does anyone know what the specific rules are?

(As an example of my confusion, my room has a fully stocked minibar, and there's a full bar downstairs, but I wasn't allowed to take a half finished alcoholic drink from the bar back to my room)

Comment: As far as I am aware, consumption is only allowed in designated areas (for example, the bar or your room) but you cannot be seen in public with alcohol or be intoxicated. I will try to find a reference for you.

Answer (score 8):

You can drink in your room or in a bar, basically anywhere alcohol is a available you can drink, no alcohol, no drink, that includes walking with a drink in public.

The reason behind this is the public resistance to "westernizing" the country, so government is trying to make everyone happy as much as possible, people who drink can drink in designated places, and the public won't feel the dramatic changes from their point of view.